# Firebase .where('smth','==',true) query doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

using multiple queries like `.where("status", "==", true)` I get nothing, my 'snapshot' is empty [screenshot 1](https://pp.userapi.com/c855632/v855632265/25a7d/Pdo7I7TqUz8.jpg), but it must return all docs, where "status" is not empty.

```
var firstLoad = () => {

var first = $scope.colRef
    .where("status", "==", true)
    .where("manager", "==", true)
    .orderBy("last_activity_date", 'desc')
    .limit(25);

first.get()
    .then(firstSnapshot => {
        console.log(firstSnapshot);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
firstLoad();
```

Then, I change query, now its like `.where("status", "==", "Потенциальный")`, Im getting correct answer  [screenshot 2](https://pp.userapi.com/c855632/v855632265/25a86/CSHf2_nCRXw.jpg).

I wonder, how to get all these docs, where "status" is not empty using `.where`?

Comment: @ponury-kostek Firestore currently doesn't have inequality queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have a way to express "not empty" in a query.  You can check for equality (as you have observed).  You have at least possible alternative.  Store another boolean field in the document, and set that to true to represent "not empty status", and false for "empty status".

Comment: Could you get away with something similar to `.orderBy('status').startAt("")` which works in RTDB? Not that it helps in this instance.

Comment: It might be possible to query for > "".